# Using Index Match where a match lookup can be one of multiple values

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

The below formula is an index-match that accurately returns the value `Calibrate Temperature Tx` if it is found within my dataset.

```
=INDEX('Equipment Strategy Review'!$C$6:$AK$3983,MATCH(1,('Equipment Strategy Review'!$C$6:$C$3983=[@[Corrected Equipment Tag]])*('Equipm**strong text**ent Strategy Review'!$AK$6:$AK$3983="Calibrate Temperature Tx"),0),35)
```

I need to expand this formula to also return values such as `Calibrate Pressure Tx` or `Calibrate Flow Tx` if found. How can this be achieved?

**Note**: No individual piece of equipment (Field C in Equipment Strategy Review) will have more than one record containing any of these strings i.e. Equipment A can only have a one of these calibration tasks, not all 3.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried combining it with an IF Function?

Comment: Can you provide a code example expanding on what you’re suggesting? How would you combine this with an `IF()` function to resolve the problem?

Comment: Do you have an example of your datasheet and result list?

Comment: Well, it's not my question, but generally if the OP _hasn't_ tried using an `IF()` function here, I'm assuming they're going to need more guidance than simply asking if they have used it.